# Failing to deploy a Flutter app on my attached Ipad

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I am developing a personal flutter app on a Mac and trying to deploy to my Ipad attached by USB.
I have created a provisioning profile on my Apple developer account however I don't know how to use it for Flutter.

My error from Android builder is:

```
Launching lib/aopAppMain.dart on Chris’s iPad in debug mode...
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "iPhone Developer: chrisr@instantobjects.com (XXXXXXX)"
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            1.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    Code Signing Error: "Runner" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor.
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.0'
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.0'
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.0'
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Chris’s iPad.
```

If I load the project in XCode it only has an Info tab and a Build Settings tab.
If I fire up a swift project, the Provisioning Profile assignment seems to happen on the General Tab and at least my Flutter project hasn't got one of those in XCode.

Comment: My current theory is that it is to do with an old Flutter project template and a recent OSX/Xcode upgrade. My reason for thinking this is that Flutter Create xxx works fine and deploys onto my Ipad fine.

Comment: Did you check this? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15335

Comment: Thanks hemnath but it seems unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I used flutter create to create a new app and migrated my source across and everything is now ok.